# Creating an array with top scores

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am very new to coding and I am trying to get my head around the basics. I have a function that iterates through an array holding scores and enters them into the topScores array with they are higher than an item in that array. This may seem useless but i want to know why it stops after hitting the secound item in the scores array.

```
var scores = [60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
var topScores = [];
function arrayAn (score) {
    for (i = 0; i < score.length; i++){
        if (score[i] > topScores){
            topScores.push(score[i])
}}}
arrayAn(scores)
console.log(topScores) // [60, 70]
```

Comment: `topScores` is an array. `score[i] > topScores` will not do what you want it to, try it in the console, e.g.: `4 > [1, 2, 3];`, it will give `false`.

Comment: You've defined the function, but you're not actually calling it anywhere.

Comment: PS: it would help, if you would state, what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stops after 2 numbers because you are no longer checking against a single number, but an array of numbers.

1. The first iteration of the loop you are checking is:

**60 > nothing**

Nothing because the array is empty at the start. topScores is now [60]

2. Next you are checking

**70 > 60**

which it is so you will now have 2 numbers in your topScores array. [60,70]

After that the topScores array will have more than 1 number so it will fail the check for being greater than the number you are checking because it is now a full array.

For this to be of any use you would have to add a check somewhere like, if the current score is less then 70 then dont add it to the top scores array. Then it would have some meaning.

Hope that helps.

```js
var scores = [60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
var topScores = [];

function arrayAn(score) {
  for (i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
    
    console.log(score[i] + " > " + topScores);
    
    if (score[i] > topScores) {
      topScores.push(score[i]);
    }
    
    
  }
}
arrayAn(scores);
console.log(topScores); // [60, 70]
```